# Detecting 'keysmashing' in a chat

Tags: algorithm, chat, spam, spam-prevention

A growing trend, especially among the tumblr audience, is 'keysmashing.' Where, instead of using actual words to express ones excitement or disbelief, they literally resort to typing random characters such as 'fsdakhf;adskh' or in all caps like 'FMDSOIAHO;EAHF.'

It also seems to be one of those influential things, where as soon as one user does it, others begin to do it too. Before long, you see something like

> User1: <insert funny comment/link>
>   User2: i jus saklfjdldsahf8fh
>   User2: cant evneaoiufhapisf
>   User3: bahasaiofhj9pdfsbdsf
>   User4: lol omg
>   User2: faisohkj

This, as you can imagine, becomes very spammy in a chat. So, without resorting to having to use some kind of autocorrect/dictionary, are there any decent methods of detecting these speech patterns?

Comment: check for words longer than usual maybe?

Comment: That could be one variable to weigh based on, but that alone would not do a very good job, I'm afraid.

Comment: can you detect typing speed? if it goes higher that usually then you know something is off.

Comment: First thought is to look for keys that are close to each other in the string. Typically, I find people drum their fingers to do this. That usually results in hitting keys along the fingers (i.e., asdf, oiuy, vcxz, etc.). Just an idea to start with.